# SmartThings/Google Home with Samsung UN55KS9000 TV

Tags: google-home, samsung-smartthings, smart-tv

My end goal is for the TV to work with Google Home.

Since its a Samsung smart TV from 2016 I first have to setup it up with SmartThings. Unfortunately, the new ST app doesn't have any option for the KS9000 model; but I'd read that the classic ST (older version) used to be able to integrate with it.

How do I get my TV setup for SmartThings?

I heard that Classic ST is completely shut down, so I haven't tried installing the older apk.

Comment: See https://community.smartthings.com/t/update-2016-samsung-tv-smartthings-integration-beware-its-false-advertising-update-not-anymore/79438/61  If that doesn't work for you, that forum maybe a good one to ask this question on.

Comment: `TV to work with Google Home` ... how do you want it to work? ... have you considered an external device  such as a Raspberry Pi or a micro PC?

Comment: @jsotola I'm just experimenting with available 'smart' electronics to get them talking to each other - using Pi / VM image to setup Home Assistant may be a better solution, but I only want to wire any existing devices that should be working together for now.

Answer (score 1):

After I posted this question, at some point I checked the SmartThings app and something in my previous attempts must've worked as I can now see the TV and control it from within ST.

I plan to remove it and try Scan Nearby Devices option (suggested by kalyanswaroop) to verify this is how to add it; will update answer once I do so.